# Android Eclipse No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to create an android project.

But i am getting following exception.

[image]

```
2016-03-18 23:46:40 - ActivityLifeCycleTest] F:\AndroidEclipse\ActivityLifeCycleTest\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-03-18 23:46:40 - ActivityLifeCycleTest] 
[2016-03-18 23:46:40 - ActivityLifeCycleTest] F:\AndroidEclipse\ActivityLifeCycleTest\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-03-18 23:46:40 - ActivityLifeCycleTest] 
[2016-03-18 23:46:40 - ActivityLifeCycleTest] F:\AndroidEclipse\ActivityLifeCycleTest\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

[image]

Comment: Import and add AppCompactSupport-v7 lib in your project.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to give proper format to your question. Here is a [Markdown guide](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) in case you are not familiar with it, and  the doc regarding [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You have appcompat_v7 there in your workspace. Add it to your dependencies.

Comment: use android studio not eclipse